# Does Upsert statement executes on data set in order

Tags: sql, timestamp, upsert

There are two columns in Database Table (Key and TimeStamp).

Lets assume, there are three rows in the data set with same Key but with different timestamp. The dataset is **sorted** based on Timestamp.

If the Upsert on the table is executed on this data set, will the last row(with latest timestamp - because of order by) be there in the database table or the execution order is not guaranteed?

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Damith: I want to upsert the record with latest timestamp.

Comment: "*The data in table is sorted*" - no, it's not. Data in a relational database is ***NOT SORTED***. Also please specify which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I meant the data in the dataset is sorted. Sorry for the confusion. I am on SAP HANA